# First web page done - can't keep the footer down

Tags: html, css

So I'm developing my first ever page after I've studied for about 3-4 months about HTML and CSS.
The problem is that the footer is sticked to the slideshow. Can't really seem to figure out how to stick it to the bottom of the page.
Also, if you find any other errors or you have any other tips for me, please mention them.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>x</title>
    <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/sshow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="shadow">
            <header id="top">
                <nav id="top-mic">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Despre noi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Locatie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="davnic" id="logo" width="288" height="115"></img></a>
                <div id="top-mare-wrap">
                    <nav id="top-mare">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                <img src="img/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <img src="img/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <img src="img/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            
            <script src="js/sshow.js"></script>

            <footer class="site-footer">
                x
                <img src="img/location_1.png" />
            </footer>     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

sshow.css

```html
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

.slideshow-container {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.active {
    background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 11px
    }
}
```

css.css

```html
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    height: 4000px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ADADAD;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#top-mic {
    background-color: #F28A00;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#top-mic ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#top-mic li {
        float: right;
        padding: 8px 30px;
}

#top-mic li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.6em;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
        margin-right: 55px;
}

#top-mic li a:hover {
    color: #ADADAD;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 130px;
}

#top-mare-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#top-mare {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

#top-mare ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-mare li {
    display:inline;
}

#top-mare li a {
        margin-top: 42px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ADADAD;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#top-mare li a:hover {
        color: #F28A00;
}

#test {
    color:black;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -142px;
}

    #container:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }

    .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
        height: 142px;
    }

.site-footer {
    background: orange;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 4000px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #F28A00;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've observed that if i delete position:relative from the sshow.css, it works, but the buttons from the slideshow obviously disappear.
Also tried with this css:

```html
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    height: 4000px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ADADAD;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#top-mic {
    background-color: #F28A00;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#top-mic ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#top-mic li {
        float: right;
        padding: 8px 30px;
}

#top-mic li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.6em;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
        margin-right: 55px;
}

#top-mic li a:hover {
    color: #ADADAD;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 130px;
}

#top-mare-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#top-mare {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

#top-mare ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-mare li {
    display:inline;
}

#top-mare li a {
        margin-top: 42px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ADADAD;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#top-mare li a:hover {
        color: #F28A00;
}

#test {
    color:black;
}

.footer {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `position: fixed` for the footer

Answer (score 1):

try closing div before the footer. the footer is inside the slide show, but i did'nt tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.footer {
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: white;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 25px;
}
```

It will always have this footer at the bottom, black background and small width above. Height is 25px. You can style this footer in the CSS. Also note that the `position` is fixed.

EDIT:
I didnt test your code, make sure div's are closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` for the footer element.